# Passing subdomain info to controller in IRouteConstraint.Match

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, subdomain

In subdomain route constraint I want to pass subdomain name to controller with the code below. But in controller subdomain entry is missing (only action and controller entries exist). What is wrong here? Or should I sniff subdomain in controller itself (with the help of Request.Headers["HOST"])? What is the best practice?

```
public class SubdomainRouting : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        //
        //get subdomain here
        //

        if (values.ContainsKey("subdomain") == false)
        {
            values.Add("subdomain", subdomain);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I changed my routing constraint implementation. Instead of implementing IRouteConstraint, I implemented RouteBase. This way I was able to add route values:

```
public class SubdomainRoute : RouteBase
{
    public override RouteData GetRouteData(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        RouteData returnValue = null;

        //some code here 

        returnValue = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
        returnValue.Values.Add("controller", "SomeController");
        returnValue.Values.Add("action", "SomeAction");
        returnValue.Values.Add("key", some_value_to_pass_to_controller);

        //some code here

        return returnValue;
    }

    public override VirtualPathData GetVirtualPath(RequestContext requestContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how did you use your SubdomainRoute class when mapping routes in RegisterRoutes? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are interpreting the `values` argument the wrong way. According the MSDN, it is *An object that contains the parameters for the URL*. So I'm not sure if its even the same RouteDataDictionary you get in the controller.

The easiest way to get the subdomain would be from the Request.Url.Host you get in the controller.